# Jquery/Dropzone.js Get the current index of an added image

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am building a custom Dropzone.js: http://www.dropzonejs.com/ layout. The upload is working well. I am wanting to save additional data in the form that the Dropzone is in for a specific post.

I need to index the array so that all the data is posted is relevant in the array.

The 'previewTemplate' allows for strings only - no function.

eg: lead_image[ INDEX HERE ][filename]

```
uploader.dropzone({
        url: "/admin/upload",
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        thumbnailWidth: 80,
        thumbnailHeight: 80,
        parallelUploads: 20,
        autoProcessQueue: true, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
        clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
        previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
        init: function() {
            this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                var index = $('li.image').length;
            });
        },
        previewTemplate:     '<li class="image row dd-item">' +
                                '<div class="col-sm-1 dd-handle">' +
                                    '<span class="preview">' +
                                        '<img data-dz-thumbnail />' +
                                    '</span>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="col-sm-8">' +
                                    '<p><span class="name" data-dz-name></span> | <span class="size" data-dz-size></span></p>' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="lead_image[ INDEX HERE ][filename]" data-dz-name/>' +
                                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lead_image[ INDEX HERE ][title]" value="" placeholder="Title" />' +
                                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lead_image[ INDEX HERE ][alt]" value="" placeholder="Alt Tag" />' +
                                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lead_image[ INDEX HERE ][caption]" value="" placeholder="Caption" />' +
                                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lead_image[ INDEX HERE ][sort]" value="" placeholder="Sort Order" />' +
                                    '<strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="col-sm-2">' +
                                    '<button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i><span>Delete</span></button>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</li>',
    });
```

I am having difficulty passing the template the index of the current item as these items are passed through later.

Has anyone dealt with this or can see a solution? I am currently trying to inject the file name as the index as a solution, but this isn't the best way to go in my mind.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help.

Comment: Hi, did you figure out a solution? I'm facing a similar issue. Could use some help. Thanks

Comment: Hi @ShifaKhan, yeah. I did sort this. Please see the response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bI sorted this in the end.

```
init: function() {

   this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {

       console.log(responseText);

       // Create the hidden fields
       // Created_at
       file.createdat = Dropzone.createElement("<input type=\"hidden\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" name=\"" + this.options.inputName + "[" + responseText.id + "][created_at]\" value=\"" + responseText.created_at + "\" />");
       file.previewElement.appendChild(file.createdat);
   }
}
```

On the init function, you are basically waiting to hear back from Dropzone of the successful uploaded. So, depending on your server side implementation, you can pass back any data you want about the file. In my case, I stored it in the DB and returned the row's info.

From there, to save that information in in the current post, I just created some hidden fields to store the data and then repeated the above for each hidden field I wanted. You can of course add other non-hidden fields for things like alt tags, titles or anything you like.

The index I was after in the the responseText: `this.options.inputName + "[" + responseText.id + "][created_at]`

Hope it helps.

As a side note, you can also do the same thing when loading files that have been stored on the server that you want to retrieve for this specific post. Just Google mockfile and dropzone and you should find a million results helping you. Its the same principle.